# Change locale in timevis

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

Don't get the german locale to work:

```
timevis(
  data.frame(id = 1:2,
             content = c("one", "two"),
             start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12")),
             options = list(locale = c("de"))
)
```

still results in *"January"* etc. instead of *"Januar"* ...